# Can a server execute a script (stored remotely on the server) on a client's machine?

Tags: python, django, server

Here's the entire desired process:

I have a client-server architecture where the server is implemented using Django.
The client (located outside the server's network):

1. Connects to my server from a browser;
2. Executes a script to package the images and other necessary files for
   the processing;
3. Upload the packaged files to my server;
4. My server processes the images;
5. My server sends the processed images back to the client.

My question is: can the server execute in anyway the script/executable that does the packaging on the client's machine? The script would be in Python or C.

The main reason behind this question is that I want my script to remain on the server's side and I want to keep the client as thin as possible; I don't want to keep anything on the client's side except the package the script would generate and the returned data from the processing. If no solution exists, I would have the script on the client's machine.

I started looking into RPyC, but since I have very little insight into how I could do this, I am here gathering suggestions.

Comment: No, the server cannot reach into the client's machine through the browser to execute arbitrary programs or directly access any files. You'd need to at least write a browser plugin of some sort that enables that reach.

Comment: The capability to interact with the client's hard drive via a web server was not considered a good feature for browsers for security reasons, and thus I think they are designed not to allow it. I am not sure about what your underlying problem is, so not sure what best alternative is. When I think of doing something on the client side with the help of the server, I think of  at least a thin script on the client that requests things from the server through a restful api or the like.